# RVIZ cannot be initialized

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At the very beginning, the PC cannot be started, after remove the memory and plug back to the slot, the PC could be started. When I run some code, the rviz cannot be started, then I check the RVIZ alone, but it failed again. Corresponding terminal shows as the following:

rct@rct-desktop:~$ rosrun rviz rviz
[ INFO] [1343613623.837962392]: rviz revision number 1.6.7
[ INFO] [1343613623.838106591]: ogre_tools revision number 1.6.2
[ INFO] [1343613623.838141246]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1343613623.959114452]: Loading general config from [/home/rct/.rviz/config]
[ INFO] [1343613627.563457011]: Loading display config from [/home/rct/.rviz/display_config]
[ INFO] [1343613630.289202872]: RTT Preferred Mode is PBuffer.
[ INFO] [1343613630.856044878]: Texture for pass 0: creating with size 1 x 1
[ INFO] [1343613630.866175438]: Texture for pass 1: creating with size 1 x 1

GLib-ERROR **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.24.1/glib/gmem.c:137: failed to allocate 251658321 bytes
aborting...
Aborted
rct@rct-desktop:~$ exitallelujah@allelujah-desktop:~/datarecord/rviz$

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40114/rviz-cannot-be-initialized/) by [allelujah-wang](https://answers.ros.org/users/2945/allelujah-wang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2012-07-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allelujah-wang](https://answers.ros.org/users/2945/allelujah-wang/) on 2012-07-29**:
Sorry that there is no room to reply to wiki, but to update the software does not work. I think Lorenz could be right, I will clear the memory manually. THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think this is really a problem with ROS or rviz. Rather, I think you might have a broken memory module that reduces the amount of RAM that is available. It seems like rviz is just unable to allocate enough memory.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1